# Getting facebox to work in the qcodo/qcube php framework

Tags: php, facebox, qcodo

I am using a framework called qcodo (which forked as qcubed) and is a PHP framework.

I want to do a very simple popup using the Facebox jquery plugin.

When someone clicks on the link and shown below in line 47.

Here is the file:  http://github.com/allyforce/AF-upload/blob/master/Templates/profile_activity.tpl.php

```
<a href="complete_profile_popup.php?allyId=<?= $this->objAllyUser->Id?>" rel="facebox" title="Complete Profile" >Invite as Ally</a><br />
```

The Facebook installation worked fine, tested it just opening plain html and php files.

I just want to be able to render a working page within the Facebox pop-up.

But the current error is that it cannot recognize the method, even though it appears it has been defined.

UPDATE:  Per one suggestion, used iFrame, but still getting nothing:

Answer (score 0):

You should print the error you get. I will try to guess: have you declared your method as public? In the template you can access only public properties and methods. This is a very common mistake.

Comment: Hi, I actually don't get any errors.  Are you on the qcodo forum I'd like to ask some follow up about your transition to rails...?  Seen others posting about it and would like your thoughts.....

Comment: I do not use Qcodo forum a lot. I just do my Qcodo's programming and moving to Rails. I think I will publish my post today. I can reach me by email rtacconi (at) gmail dot com and we can help each other in Qcodo to Rails issues.

Answer (score 0):

This issue/topic is being discussed in depth at http://www.qcodo.com/forums/forum.php/3/4007/

Comment: Still isn't working and the qcodo forum seem non-responsive at this point...thanks.